# How did Jethro know Moshe's God?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu, shemot-exodus

Jethro appeared to be a friendly guy to Moshe, and even appeared to agree with what Moshe believed in, especially in theological terms (i.e. worshipping Hashem).

If that's the case, then how did Jethro know Hashem, a Jewish God? How was he already an established priest of Hashem, even though he didn't go to Egypt and interact with the enslaved Klal Yisrael etc.?

Comment: By definition, polytheism believes in the existence of many gods.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. He was a priest of  Midian, not Hashem. When he heard about the Exodus and the incident at Yam Suf, he decided to convert. There are midradshim that place him in Egypt as the head of Paroh's ministers.

Comment: @Lucian The text says he was a priest of Midian, not a polytheist

Comment: @ba: [And](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midian#Religion) ?